# Splitting a string into an array of words in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to make a function that splits a cstring into an array of words. Eg. if I send in "Hello world" then I'd get an array with two places where the 1st place has the element "Hello", second "world". I'm getting segmentation fault and I can't for the life of me figure out what seems to be wrong.

- In the for-loop I am checking how many spaces there are, which determines how many words there are in total (spacing is always N-1, N = number of words). Then I tell the program to add 1 to the counter (Because of N-1).
- I declare a char* array[] in order to keep each of the individual words seperated, not sure if I need counter+1 here (because of the \0?)
- This is where the tricky part comes in. I use strtok to seperate each words (using " "). I then malloc each position of char*array[] so that it has enough memory to store the words. This is done until there are no more words to put in.

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint of which part is causing the segmentation fault!

```
void split(char* s){

    int counter = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    for(int i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++){
        if(s[i] == ' '){
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    counter += 1;

    char* array[counter+1];

    char *token = strtok(s, " ");

    while(token != NULL){
        array[pos] = malloc(strlen(token));
        strcpy(array[pos], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        pos++;
    }
```

Comment: `malloc(strlen(token))` --> `malloc(strlen(token)+1)`

Comment: in order to find where it fails, a) run under a debugger, b) use valgrind (If using linux)

Comment: c) just add print statements like a sane person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I send in "Hello world" then I'd get an array with two places where
>   the 1st place has the element "Hello", second "world".

No. You can't pass a string literal to that function. Because `strtok()` modifies its input. So, it'll attempt to modify string literal, resulting in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Be aware of the limitations of `strtok()`. From the man page of `strtok()`:

> ```
>    Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note
>    that:
>
>    * These functions modify their first argument.
>
>    * These functions cannot be used on constant strings.
>
>    * The identity of the delimiting byte is lost.
>
>    * The strtok() function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's
>      not thread safe.  Use strtok_r() if this matters to you.
> ```

So, you need to pass a pointer to a modifiable memory location if you want to use `strtok()`.

---

As BLUPIXY pointed out, your `malloc()` call doesn't allocate sufficient space. You need one more byte than the string length (for the terminating nul byte).

Comment: Pass a pointer to  a modifiable memory location? Could you give an example? I thought char* s (parameter) is already a pointer

Comment: For example: passing an array. `char arr[] = "Hello world"; split(arr);`

Comment: Ohhhh I see. I'll experiment with this then report back how it goes!

Comment: Man, thank you so much for the help! I was able to fix the problem by passing an array to the split function. Couple of questions: when you wrote "string literal" does that mean that I aren't able to write "split("hello world)" but instead I need to make an variable which stores the string in and then send the variable into the split() function?

Comment: `char arr[] = "Hello world";` *copies* it. But if you had `char *p = "hello world"; split(arr);` you'll have exactly the same problem. So, it's not passing a variable that makes the difference but *what* you pass.